# How to auto trigger an onclick function in dynamically added HTML element using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing an attach files project where I need to auto check a file name when there is only one file to be chosen to attach. It is easy to auto check it as a checkbox, but when it is checked, there is an onclick function called to update the file in the server side.

Since the `<input>` tag is dynamically added based on the number of required attaching files, `.trigger('click')` didn't work on it.

```
$.each(speedLetterArray, function (key, value) {
    var idLine = fileId + '_b' + value.reasonCode;
    var idContainer = 'sliC_f' + idLine;
    var idItem = 'sli_f' + idLine;
    output.push('<div style="' + cssDisplay + '" class="sliContainer" id="' + idContainer + '">');
    //auto checked if only one item
    if (fileCount == speedLetterArray.length) {
        value.isSelected = 'true';
    }
    if (value.isSelected == 'true') {
        output.push('<input id="' + idItem + '"  onclick="updateSpeedLetterItemLists(this);" type="checkbox" name="' + idItem + '" value="' + value.reasonCode + '" class="testClass" style="margin:0px;" />');
    } else {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

I used `checked=checked` to auto check the file, but couldn't trigger the onclick function `updateSpeedLetterItemLists(this)`  to update the files on server side. 
which works fine when I manually click it.

I tried  `$(.sliContainer).find('input:checkbox:first').trigger('click');` after the `<input>` tag or in `$(document).ready`, either of them works.

I thought maybe I didn't find the right object since when I use `alert($(.sliContainer).find('input:checkbox:first').val())` I get "undefined" value.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$('yourelemtid').click()
```

Or since it is dynamically added

```
$( "yourelemtid" ).live( "click", function() {

});
```

Since the element is added after the initial javascript initialization it won't see your new elements to add the hooks onto.

[jQuery Doc for .live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: `$( "document" ).on( "click" ,"yourelementid", function() {

});`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but all I need is AUTO TRIGGER THE ONCLICK without click the element mannually, live or on is only used to bind the click event to html element,

Answer (score 0):

.live is deprecated, use this:

```
$(document).on( "click", "#yourelemtid", function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: thanks , it is the same as the first answer, what I need is auto trigger the onclick function without manually clicking.